# What are the 2-categorical mono/epimorphisms in the 2-category of relations?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

$\newcommand{\procirc}{\mathbin{\diamond}}\newcommand{\rightproarrow}{\mathrel{\rightarrow\mkern-17mu|\mkern7mu}}$The monomorphisms in the 1-category $\mathsf{Rel}$ of sets and relations are precisely those relations $R\colon A\rightproarrow B$ whose direct image functions
$$R_*\colon\mathcal{P}(A)\to\mathcal{P}(B)$$
are injective.

Now, $R$ is a monomorphism in $\mathsf{Rel}$ precisely if the map
$$R_*\colon\mathrm{Rel}(X,A)\to\mathrm{Rel}(X,B)$$
is injective for each $X\in\mathrm{Obj}(\mathsf{Rel})$. However, there is also the 2-category $\mathbf{Rel}$ of sets, relations, and inclusions of relations, and it thus makes sense to ask whether the functor of posetal categories
$$R_*\colon\mathsf{Rel}(X,A)\to\mathsf{Rel}(X,B)$$
is full, faithful, or fully faithful.

As it turns out, this functor is always faithful, with fullness corresponding to the following condition:

1. For each set $X$ and each pair of relations $S,T\colon X⇸A$, if $R\procirc S\subset R\procirc T$, then $S\subset T$.

Call a relation satisfying such a condition a "full monomorphism in the 2-category $\mathbf{Rel}$". Repeating all this for epimorphisms, we see that the "full epimorphisms in $\mathbf{Rel}$" are those relations $R$ satisfying the following condition:

2. For each set $X$ and each pair of relations $S,T\colon X⇸A$, if $S\procirc R\subset T\procirc R$, then $S\subset T$.

**Question:** Is there a nice characterisation of the full monomorphisms (resp. the full epimorphisms) in the 2-category of sets, relations, and inclusions of relations?

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\procirc}{\mathbin{\diamond}}\newcommand{\rightproarrow}{\mathrel{\rightarrow\mkern-17mu|\mkern7mu}}$I just realised one can apply pretty much the same argument for showing that 1-categorical monomorphisms $R$ in $\mathsf{Rel}$ are such that $R_*$ is injective to prove the following:

> The following conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. The relation $R\colon A\rightproarrow B$ is a full monomorphism in $\mathbf{Rel}$.
> 2. The functor
>    $$R_*\colon(\mathcal{P}(A),\subset)\to(\mathcal{P}(B),\subset)$$
>    is full, i.e., for each $U,V\in\mathcal{P}(A)$, if $R(U)\subset R(V)$, then $U\subset V$.

A similar statement holds for "full epimorphisms" with $R^{-1}$ in place of $R_*$.

Comment: (I'm leaving the question open however, since perhaps (hopefully?) there might be extra characterisations besides this one.)